# want to add a "$" to one item in a php row being fetched from a database

Tags: php, mysql

When I fetch items from a database using php and mysql, I usually just push each row into an array:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
}
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8'); //important! or it won't echo the array

$data = array();
$q = "SELECT distinct(procedure_codes), procedure_name FROM `hospital_transparency_data` order by procedure_codes";
$result = $db->query($q);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row; //whole row goes in
}
    
$db->close();
echo json_encode($data);
```

But in this case, I want to push each item in the $row into the array individually because I want to add a dollar sign to one of the row items. I still want the name of the field associated with its value, I guess kind of like "`full_payer_name"-->$row["full_payer_name"]`. How would I do that?

```
$datastring = $_POST['datastring'];
        
$q = "SELECT procedure_name, procedure_codes, hospital_name, raw_description, full_payer_name, plan_type, price FROM `hospital_transparency_data` where " . $datastring . " order by procedure_name, hospital_name, full_payer_name";
        
 $result = $db->query($q);
 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //Add this row to the reply
    array_push($data, $row["procedure_name"], $row["procedure_codes"],  $row["hospital_name"], $row["raw_description"], $row["full_payer_name"], $row["plan_type"], "$" . $row["price"]); 
//works, but doesn't have the field name associated with the value
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `$` to the row element before pushing onto the array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row['price'] = '$' . $row['price'];
    $data[] = $row; //whole row goes in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add it as part of the SQL, this means you don't need to do anything special with the result set.  Use `CONCAT('$', price)` to add it...

```
$q = "SELECT procedure_name, procedure_codes, hospital_name, 
             raw_description, full_payer_name, plan_type, 
             CONCAT('$', price) as price 
         FROM `hospital_transparency_data` 
         where " . $datastring . " 
         order by procedure_name, hospital_name, full_payer_name";
```

You may also be able to use [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) which stops you having to loop over each row to add it in.

Comment: This is correct, but I had to do additional formatting for my price value, so I went with Barmar's solution. However, your solution will be very helpful in the future for me. Thank you!